# What does the lambda parameter in the paper "Interpretable Explanations of Black Boxes by Meaningful Perturbation" do?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, papers, optimization, explainable-ai

I do not understand the purpose of the $\lambda$ parameter in equation 3 of the paper [Interpretable Explanations of Black Boxes by Meaningful Perturbation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03296.pdf).

$$m^{*}=\underset{m \in[0,1]^{\Lambda}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \lambda\|\mathbf{1}-m\|_{1}+f_{c}\left(\Phi\left(x_{0} ; m\right)\right) \tag{3}\label{3}$$

As far as I understand, the argmin function returns the $m$ for which the term $\lambda\|\mathbf{1}-m\|_{1}$ is smallest. If that's the case, I don't understand the purpose of $\lambda$, since it doesn't change the result of $m$.